# How much was cost for a regular (standard class) passenger to come on passenger ship from Liverpool England to Canada between 1906-1908

Tags: travel

What was the approximate, cost and length of trip in days to cross Atlantic from Liverpool England to New York USA or Quebec Canada, in the regular class of a passenger steamship between 1906-1908.

Comment: Which destination: St. John N.B., Halifax, Quebec City, or Montreal? "*As she sails*" distance from Halifax to Q.C. is 958 nautical miles, at least a days sail.

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify where you've searched and what you found already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help] and, in particular, [ask].

Answer (score 5):

Brandon DuPont, Drew Keeling and Thomas Weiss published a [paper](https://www.eh.net/eha/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Weissetal.pdf) looking at fares over a long period.

Figure 5 shows that transatlantic fares in the Edwardian era were typically around $25 or £5 for steerage passengers. Second class and first class would be around double and quadruple although this varied much more between companies.

Slightly cheaper rates might be obtained in winter and traveling East than in summer or travelling West. The migrant trade was predominantly people travelling one way from east to west though persons travelling for business or pleasure might go either way.

Emigrants from the British Isles to Canada might obtain vouchers including onward rail travel at reduced rates in order to encourage settlement.

Answer (score 2):

In 1904 Canadian Pacific Railway commissioned two sister ships, [*RMS Empress of Ireland*](http://ssmaritime.com/Empress-of-Ireland-1906.htm) and [*RMS Empress of Britain*](http://www.clydeships.co.uk/view.php?ref=6417), to commence operation on the lucrative Liverpool to Quebec (St. John, New Brunswick in winter) run inn 1906. Both had a cruising speed of 18 knots and a maximum speed of 20 knots, allowing the westward passage from Liverpool to Quebec City to be completed in an advertised "*less than 4 days at sea*", followed by a more leisurely 2 days sailing up the scenic St. Lawrence.

Both vessels remained on this route up to the 1914, when [Empress of Ireland](http://ssmaritime.com/Empress-of-Ireland-The-Final-Voyage.htm) was sunk after being rammed amidships by the wayward icebreaker/collier Storstad, and *Empress of Britain* was sold off as a troopship.